# Is there any solution for converting openapi3 to Restdocs(adoc)?

Tags: openapi, spring-restdocs

I could convert openapi2 to adoc with Swagger2Markup, but it support only openapi2, not 3.

https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup/issues

and I read some issues on it, and i guess it still does not support openapi3. so is there any plugin about it?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to convert your OpenAPI 3.0 definition to an HTML/HTMl2 doc.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to https://editor.swagger.io
2. Import (File-->Import) or Paste your OpenAPI 3.0 YAML/JSON definition.
3. Select Generate Client > html or html2.
4. Download & unzip the file.
5. Open the index.html page in a browser.